# Branch Universal Deep Link does not display custom view controller elements

Tags: uiwebview, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

So I have a Universal link that leads to a view controller in my app. On that particular view controller I display a couple of images as well as a web view. The webView displays a url chosen by the user. How do I save this custom url so that it is displayed every time someone clicks the link? I think the code to this is under:

```
@synthesize deepLinkingCompletionDelegate;
 -(void)configureControlWithData:(NSDictionary *)data {


NSString *string = data[@"favoriteArticle"];
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to accomplish. You want a user to click a link, and then _after they have clicked it_, update the data contained in that link?

Comment: Here's the idea: My App displays a list of articles (RSS FEED). Every article is displayed on a view controller with a web view. The user can share the article through Universal Links. When someone clicks on the Universal link they are directed to my app where they can read the article (which is a view controller with a web view). The problem is, when I click on the Universal Link from Notes, I am directed to a view controller with a blank web view. How do I save the custom url/article (on the webView) the user chose to share via Universal Link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here:

To accomplish this, you need to do two things.

### Step 1

Store the URL of the article you want to load as one of the Branch link custom parameters. Full instructions on how to do that [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/creating-links/apps/ios/), but essentially:

```c
BranchUniversalObject *branchUniversalObject = [[BranchUniversalObject alloc] initWithCanonicalIdentifier:@"item/12345"];
branchUniversalObject.title = @"My Content Title";
branchUniversalObject.contentDescription = @"My Content Description";
branchUniversalObject.imageUrl = @"https://example.com/mycontent-12345.png";
[branchUniversalObject addMetadataKey:@"favorite_article" value:@"https://example.com/path/to/article"]; // this is used to route inside the app
[branchUniversalObject addMetadataKey:@"property2" value:@"red"];

BranchLinkProperties *linkProperties = [[BranchLinkProperties alloc] init];
linkProperties.feature = @"sharing";
linkProperties.channel = @"facebook";
[linkProperties addControlParam:@"$desktop_url" withValue:@"https://example.com/path/to/article"]; // this is used for desktop visitors
[linkProperties addControlParam:@"$ios_url" withValue:@"https://example.com/path/to/article"]; // this is used for iOS mobile visitors without the app installed
```

### Step 2

Then when the app opens after a link click, watch for that data key. Again, [full instructions](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/guide/), but basically:

```c
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  // initialize the session, setup a deep link handler
  [[Branch getInstance] initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions
                          andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:^(NSDictionary *params, NSError *error) {

    // start setting up the view controller hierarchy
    UINavigationController *navC = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *nextVC;

    // If the key 'favoriteArticle' is present in the deep link dictionary
    // then load the picture screen with the appropriate picture
    NSString * favoriteArticle = [params objectForKey:@"favorite_article"];
    if (favoriteArticle) {
      nextVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ArticleVC"];
      [nextVC setArticleUrl: favoriteArticle];
    } else {
      nextVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainVC"];
    }

    // navigate!
    [navC setViewControllers:@[nextVC] animated:YES];
  }];

  return YES;
}
```

After this, in your `ArticleVC`, retrieve the `favoriteArticle` value and use it for your webview.

### Step 2 (Alternate)

The `configureControlWithData` method you mentioned is used in the [automatic deep link routing implementation](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/advanced/ios/#configure-view-controller-to-accept-deep-links). You may be able to adapt this to work with a webview, but I haven't personally tried that. It would look something like this:

```c
@synthesize deepLinkingCompletionDelegate;
- (void)configureControlWithData:(NSDictionary *)data {
    NSString *favoriteArticle = data[@"favorite_article"];

    // load the webview with the URL stored inside favoriteArticle
}
```

Comment: It works! But ever since I implemented step 2 The root view controller loads twice (I open the app and then it loads again). Also, for Step 1 my imageUrl is an image I added to my Xcode project, but when I post the Universal link on Facebook the imageUrl for the link is blank. (Note: I use deep views too).  And, the close button `- (IBAction)closePressed {
    [self.deepLinkingCompletionDelegate deepLinkingControllerCompleted];`

Comment: doesn't close the View Controller (via. Universal Links). Dismissing it doesn't work either.

Comment: This is a lot to handle in answer comments — you may find it easier to [submit a ticket to the Branch integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new). Briefly though: the view controller loading twice may be a non-Branch architecture problem...hard to tell without seeing the code. The imageUrl needs to be an publicly-accessible URL (hosted on AWS, for example), not an image object from inside the app. And `deepLinkingControllerCompleted` needs to be triggered _in addition_ to dismissing the view controller yourself via standard methods.

Comment: Realized the (Step 2) `nextVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainVC"];` (under the else statement) is what is causing the view controller to load twice when someone firsts open the app (not via Universal Links). Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you trigger `MainVC` in some other way? In the example, that view controller is only loaded if the Branch link does _not_ contain the param you're looking for, so if you already go to `MainVC` in that situation, you wouldn't need this additional logic to do it twice.